# Select tuple member from a list with condition in python/pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a list  like this

```
A =[ ( 1, 10, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 11, 3), (2, 6, 4), (2, 5, 4) ]
```

I need to make a list like

```
B = [ ( 1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 4) ]
```

The condition is if first and third values of a member of A is equal to another member select the member having the smallest 2nd value.

In this example member of A is only 5 and of two group having first and third members equal.  But in my case this numbers might be high. I could not figure out how to do this with python 2.7.

Its also helpful if I get a query that is ok with pyodbc for this considering each member of A is a record and member of each tuple is a column.

Comment: I could not figure out how to write code for this or how to make loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate:

```
from sys import maxint

A =[ ( 1, 10, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 11, 3), (2, 6, 4), (2, 5, 4) ]
results = {}
for x, y, z in A:
    key = (x, z)
    results[key] = min(y, results.get(key, maxint))

results = [(x, y, z) for (x, z), y in results.items()]

print results
```